# drawAtPoint is eating memory

Tags: objective-c, image, memory-leaks, crop

I am working on an iOS app. I need crop an image which is generate from PDF.
Sometimes, the image resolution can be very big.
I use follow code to generate the cropped image. My problem is the memory is increasing all the time. Never released.

```
- (UIImage *)croppedImageWithFrame:(CGRect)frame angle:(NSInteger)angle{
UIImage *croppedImage = nil;
CGPoint drawPoint = CGPointZero;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, YES, self.scale);
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //To conserve memory in not needing to completely re-render the image re-rotated,
    //map the image to a view and then use Core Animation to manipulate its rotation
    if (angle != 0) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self];
        imageView.layer.minificationFilter = @"nearest";
        imageView.layer.magnificationFilter = @"neareset";
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, angle * (M_PI/180.0f));
        CGRect rotatedRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(imageView.bounds, imageView.transform);
        UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){CGPointZero, rotatedRect.size}];
        [containerView addSubview:imageView];
        imageView.center = containerView.center;
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -frame.origin.x, -frame.origin.y);
        [containerView.layer renderInContext:context];
    }
    else {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -frame.origin.x, -frame.origin.y);
        [self drawAtPoint:drawPoint];
    }

    croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return croppedImage;
```

}

When I debug, 
It burns 100MB in line

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, YES, self.scale);
```

then when run into follow line, it burn another 150MB

```
[self drawAtPoint:drawPoint];
```

When run to follow line, it release 100MB

```
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

after it's done, the 150MB never released

I thought UIGraphicsEndImageContext() should release all the 250MB. Why it's not?

Comment: So what does `self.drawAtPoint:` do?

Comment: And what does `self` points to?

Comment: @trojanfoe  self is an UIImage, this method is defined in a UIImage Category. So self.drawAtPoint will draw self into context